# Document.Compare ref in parameters

Tags: powershell, ms-word, ms-office

I am making a ps script to trigger Word compare via Powershell.

Following line:

```
$document.Compare($ChangedFileName, [ref]"Author", [ref]$wdCompareTargetSelected, [ref]$true, [ref]$true);
```

works fine on most systems, but for one client with Office 2013 and Windows 8.1 it throws error saying:

> Argument: '2' should not be a
>   System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Do  not use [ref].

If I remove [ref] it starts to work on that particular machine, but stops to work on other.

Is there any general solution how to make it work in all environments?

Comment: Are your other clients on Office 2010 or something?  Also, it makes zero sense to pass reference types with `[ref]`

Comment: You can remove `[ref]` from all the arguments here, the runtime will figure out how to marshal the values correctly.

Comment: unfortunately, I removed it and I get message saying use [ref] on other machines.

Comment: as a solution I decided to remove all parameters except $ChangedFileName, they're not mandatory and I do not use them. Seems like solution works on all environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Office version 2010 and lower**

I figured out that all parameters except the first one are optional. In fact these variables were always set to their defaults I was able to omit them and use following code:

```
$document.Compare($ChangedFileName);
```

**For Office version 2013 and higer**

It is possible to use other parameters too without any issues.